# Verilog seems to default an option in a case statement

Tags: case, verilog

I am writing part of a larger program staring small. I am new to verilog so any advise would be appreciated.

I am trying to write a case statement that will, once one of four buttons is pressed it will write a number (1-4) on the first of four 7 segment displays.

```
    module final(CLK,button1,button2,button3,button4,a0,b0,c0,d0,e0,f0,g0,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,f3,g3);
  input CLK,button1,button2,button3,button4;
  output a0,b0,c0,d0,e0,f0,g0,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,f3,g3; //What a mess

  integer i = 0;

  reg [6:0] temp;
  reg [6:0] sevenDisp0;
  reg [6:0] sevenDisp1;
  reg [6:0] sevenDisp2;
  reg [6:0] sevenDisp3;
  reg [2:0] place;

  initial begin
   temp = 7'b1110111;
    sevenDisp0 = 7'b1110111;
    sevenDisp1 = 7'b1110111;
    sevenDisp2 = 7'b1110111;
    sevenDisp3 = 7'b1110111;
    i = 0;

  end
    always @(button1 or button2 or button3 or button4)// or sevenDisp0 or sevenDisp1 or sevenDisp2 or sevenDisp3)//bit1 or bit2)
    begin
        case({button1,button2,button3,button4})
            4'b0111: sevenDisp0 = 7'b1001111; //Have tried 4'b1111 to troubleshoot
            4'b1011: sevenDisp0 = 7'b0010010;
            4'b1101: sevenDisp0 = 7'b0000110;
            4'b1110: sevenDisp0 = 7'b1001100;
            //default: sevenDisp0 = 7'b1110111;
        endcase
    end


  assign {a0,b0,c0,d0,e0,f0,g0} = sevenDisp0;
  assign {a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1} = sevenDisp1;
  assign {a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2} = sevenDisp2;
  assign {a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,f3,g3} = sevenDisp3;

endmodule
```

From my, very limited, understanding whenever one of my four buttons is pressed it runs the always statement. Whatever button is pressed will be written to the sevenDisp0 register.

One thing of note is that buttons register 0 when pressed and the seven segment is 0 for on.

What I see is a number one on the first seven segment. Pressing any other button will show the corresponding number while the button is pressed and switch back to the number one.

I have been trying to solve this for 6 hours now. Any help would be great.

Comment: I do not have a simulation.

Comment: In case anyone googles this in the future:

I needed to switch to non-blocking notation for the registers to actually work right.

Comment: I see a few problems here. First and foremost, you don't have any registers. Registers need a clock signal that you're not using. Your sensitivity list should *just* be `posedge CLK` if you want registers. An incomplete case (the `default` commented out) with combinational logic would infer latches with a gated latch enable (probably not what you intended). Blocking/non-blocking shouldn't really make a difference for this case, although it is good practice to always use non-blocking assignments within clocked processes.

Answer (score 1):

`sevenDisp0` in an inferred latch (level-sensitive) because it is not assigned a value in all possible paths. You should try to avoid latches as they can be the cause of unexpected behavior. Most FPGA as limited or no support for latches. You should use pure combiantional logic and flops (clock edge triggered) in your design.

If you do not want `sevenDisp0` to store its value, then use combinational logic (use blocking `=` assignment):

```
always @* // auto-sensitivity
  begin
    case({button1,button2,button3,button4})
        4'b0111: sevenDisp0 = 7'b1001111; //Have tried 4'b1111 to troubleshoot
        4'b1011: sevenDisp0 = 7'b0010010;
        4'b1101: sevenDisp0 = 7'b0000110;
        4'b1110: sevenDisp0 = 7'b1001100;
        default: sevenDisp0 = 7'b1110111; //Needed or will be a latch
    endcase
  end
```

If you do want `sevenDisp0` to store its value, then use make it sequential by triggering on the clock edge (use non-blocking `<=` assignment):

```
always @(posedge CLK)
  begin
    case({button1,button2,button3,button4})
        4'b0111: sevenDisp0 <= 7'b1001111; //Have tried 4'b1111 to troubleshoot
        4'b1011: sevenDisp0 <= 7'b0010010;
        4'b1101: sevenDisp0 <= 7'b0000110;
        4'b1110: sevenDisp0 <= 7'b1001100;
        //default: //Retain previous value of sevenDisp0
    endcase
  end
```

---

FYI: For combinational (and intentional latching) logic, you should use auto-sensitivity `@*` or the synonymous `@(*)`. Hard-coding signals in the sensitivity list is only required when required to follow the Verilog-1995 standard. Since Verilog-2001 `@*` is preferred as it doesn't run the risk of missing signals leading to behavior mismatches between RTL simulations and gates/FPGA/etc. Plus it is significantly less typing.

Another suggestion is to use ANSI style header (another feature added in Verilog-2001). This allows you to declare the port direction and type inside the port list order. It is also less typing. Example:

```
module final(
  input  CLK,
  input  button1,button2,button3,button4,
  output a0,b0,c0,d0,e0,f0,g0,    // much
  output a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,    // easier
  output a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,    // to
  output a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,f3,g3 );  // read

reg [6:0] sevenDisp0;
// ...
```